# Colorbox image effects not showing

Tags: module, drupal-7, colorbox, slide

I am new to drupal and just wanted to work on a image gallery. For this I downloaded colorbox module and installed it. Created a new content type `Gallery` with Field Type `image` and Format `colorbox` in `Manage Display` section. Basically I am following this tutorial :

[Create gallery in D7](http://jamestombs.co.uk/2011-05-26/create-album-based-image-gallery-drupal-7-using-fields-and-views)

I added content to content type `Gallery`. But when I click on the images, it does not show any effects, instead a normal image view , ie image in a new window ! Whats wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do you install module [Libraries API](https://drupal.org/project/libraries)?
2. Download plugin and unpack to sites/all/libraries/colorbox